# How to test whether a value is of type Int

Tags: swift, string, swiftui, types, integer

I have a Textfield and I want to test whether the its input value is of type Int or not.

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var integer: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter an integer", text: $integer)
        
        Button(action: {
            if (Int(integer)//here is where I want to figure out whether the value is of type Int) {
                print("Yay")
            } else {
                print("not an integer")
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Check")
        })
    }
}
```

There's gotta be a simple way to do this but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: If `Int(integer)` is not an integer, it will return `nil`.

Comment: You can also restrict input to numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Int(integer) and unwrap the optional as following:

```
if let intValue = Int(integer) {
    print("Int value: \(intValue)")
} else {
    print("Not an int")
}
```

Comment: `Int.init` has a pretty simplistic idea of which strings are integers. If you're taking in user input, then you should use `NumberFormatter` for a more locale-aware parsing (e.g. it could handle `1 234,56`)

Answer (score 2):

Simple null checking will work.

```
Button(action: {
    if Int(integer) != nil {
        print("Yay")
    } else {
        print("not an integer")
    }
}, label: {
    Text("Check")
})
```

Or with optional binding

```
Button(action: {
    if let numInt = Int(integer) {
        print("Yay")
        print(numInt)
    } else {
        print("not an integer")
    }
}, label: {
    Text("Check")
})
```